# Why is my /.is choice key not working correctly?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

This example is much longer than it really needs to be, but I don't have the time to prune it down right now (apologies!).

Everything in this example works as expected **except** the `my fill` key which is supposed to be defined as a `.is choice` key.  However, when I try to compile, LaTeX complains that

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/my fill=blue' and I am go
ing to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

If I replace each occurrence of `my fill=<color>` with `my <color>`, the code compiles correctly.

```
%-*-mode:LaTeX-*-
\documentclass[border=8]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\let\x\expandafter

\makeatletter

%-@-(1)---------------------------------------------------------------------
\long\def\if@node@defined(#1)#2#3{%%                                        
  \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}%%                                             
    {#3}%% FALSE: "yes" it's undefined                                      
    {#2}}% TRUE:  "no"  it's not undefined                                  
\def\ifsquarenodedefined#1{%%
  \x\let\x\ae@tmp\csname ae@#1@node\endcsname
  \x\if@node@defined\x(\ae@tmp){\booltrue{#1.bool}}{\boolfalse{#1.bool}}}

\providebool{nw.bool}
\providebool{ne.bool}
\providebool{sw.bool}
\providebool{se.bool}

%-@-(2)---------------------------------------------------------------------
%% First call the function to read the "optional" arguments, which really   
%% aren't so optional.  The optional arguments should be passed as          
%% [#1;#2;#3] where #1 is actually required.                                
\newcommand\aesquare{\ae@square}

%% #1=nw,ne,se,sw ==> set the right angle for the triangle to be colored    
%% #2=sets the optional arguments to be passed to the draw command.         
%% #3=sets the optional arguments to be passed to the fill command.         
\def\ae@square[#1;#2;#3]{%%
  \def\@@ae@corner{#1}%%
  \def\@@ae@draw{#2}%%
  \def\@@ae@fill{#3}
  \@ae@square}
%% This next macro is the meat of the business.  It will only draw and fill
%% the triangle defined by the passed nodes if, in fact, the nodes are     
%% already defined.                                                        
\def\@ae@square(#1,#2,#3){%%
  %%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\ae@node@nx{int(#2+1)}%%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\ae@node@ny{int(#3-1)}%%
  %% set the macros that `\ifsquarenodedefined` expects to already be
  %% defined.
  \edef\ae@nw@node{A#2#3}%%
  \edef\ae@ne@node{A\ae@node@nx#3}%%
  \edef\ae@se@node{A\ae@node@nx\ae@node@ny}%%
  \edef\ae@sw@node{A#2\ae@node@ny}%%
  %% set the booleans that will be tested next.
  \ifsquarenodedefined{nw}%%
  \ifsquarenodedefined{ne}%%
  \ifsquarenodedefined{se}%%
  \ifsquarenodedefined{sw}%%
  %% only draw and fill a triangle if the corners are all properly defined.
  \ifboolexpr{
      bool {nw.bool} and
      bool {ne.bool} and
      bool {se.bool} and
      bool {sw.bool} }
  {
    \x\ifstrequal\x{\@@ae@corner}{nw}{\ae@set{a}{sw}\ae@set{b}{nw}\ae@set{c}{ne}}{}
    \x\ifstrequal\x{\@@ae@corner}{ne}{\ae@set{a}{nw}\ae@set{b}{ne}\ae@set{c}{se}}{}
    \x\ifstrequal\x{\@@ae@corner}{se}{\ae@set{a}{ne}\ae@set{b}{se}\ae@set{c}{sw}}{}
    \x\ifstrequal\x{\@@ae@corner}{sw}{\ae@set{a}{se}\ae@set{b}{sw}\ae@set{c}{nw}}{}
    \draw[\@@ae@draw] (\ae@a) -- (\ae@b) -- (\ae@c) -- cycle;
    \fill[\@@ae@fill] (\ae@a) -- (\ae@b) -- (\ae@c) -- cycle;
  }{}}

\def\ae@set#1#2{%%
  \x\edef\csname ae@#1\endcsname{\csname ae@#2@node\endcsname}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}%%'

\begin{tikzpicture}[my dot/.style={fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt},>={To[scale=2]},
                    my colors/.style={
                      my gray/.style={gray},
                      my blue/.style={blue!30},
                      my red/.style={red},
                      my green/.style={green},
                    },
                    my same colors/.style={              
                      my gray/.style={gray},
                      my blue/.style={gray},
                      my red/.style={gray},
                      my green/.style={gray},
                    },
                    my fill/.is choice,
                    my fill/blue/.style={my blue},
                    my fill/gray/.style={my gray},
                    my fill/red/.style={my red},
                    my fill/green/.style={my green},
                    my draw/.style={line width=0.8pt},
                    my colors,
                    x=1.5cm,y=1.5cm
  ]
  \coordinate (A11) at (0,0);
  \foreach \myx in {0,...,6}
  {
    \foreach \myy in {0,...,6}
    {
      \coordinate (A\myx\myy) at (\myx,\myy);
    }
  }

  \foreach \myx in {0,...,6}
  {
    \foreach \myy in {0,...,6}
    {
      \pgfmathsetmacro\aeinta{int(\myx)}%%
      \pgfmathsetmacro\aeintb{int(\myy)}%%
      \ifnumcomp{\aeinta}{<}{3}
        { 
          \ifnumcomp{\aeintb}{<}{4}
          {
            \aesquare[ne;my draw;my fill=blue](A,\myx,\myy)
          }
          {
            \aesquare[se;my draw;my fill=red](A,\myx,\myy)
          }
        }
        {
          \ifnumcomp{\aeintb}{<}{4}
          {
            \aesquare[nw;my draw;my fill=green](A,\myx,\myy)
          }
          {
            \aesquare[sw;my draw;my fill=gray](A,\myx,\myy)
          }
        }
    }
  }

  \draw[my draw] (A00) rectangle (A66);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}%%'
```

Could someone explain how I can get my choice key to work correctly?

When working properly and when the key `my colors` is selected, the result should look as:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is not related to `.is choice` (used by `my fill=blue`). You get the same error with `fill=blue`. Your problem is related to the expansion of macro by pgfkey : pgfkey sees the key `my flll=blue` and not the key `my fill` with the value `blue`.

### First solution:

Replace :

```
\fill[\@@ae@fill]...
```

by:

```
\expandafter\fill\expandafter[\@@ae@fill]...
```

### Second solution:

Replace:

```
\def\@@ae@fill{#3}
```

by:

```
\tikzset{@@ae@fill/.style={#3}}
```

Then replace:

```
\fill[\@@ae@fill]...
```

by:

```
\fill[@@ae@fill]...
```

Comment: Something about the second approach appeals greatly to me.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit about why this is the way it is?  In particular, why is it that upon expansion of `\fill[\@@ae@fill]` that `my fill=blue` is read as one entire key, but `\expandafter\fill\expandafter[\@@ae@fill]` corrects this misreading?  Put another way, why is it that the order of expansion effects how the keys are seen?

Comment: OK, I think I just answered my own question.  I tried `\def\@@ae@fill{blue,line width=8pt}` and I got an error about *I do not know the key '/tikz/blue,line width=8pt'*.  So, if I understand correctly, the order of expansion matters because the key parser grabs `\@@ae@fill` as the entirety of the key and only then does it proceed to expand it.

Comment: @A.Ellett Good analysis!